# NeoVim hides the * chars when editing markdown

Tags: neovim, filetype-markdown

I am using [tpope's vim-markdown plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown) to edit markdown files. Somehow, neovim **hides** the `_` and `*` chars and changes the text in between to italic or bold depending on quantity of chars.  I want to see these chars. How do I configure neovim or vim-markdown to **not hide** the chars? (note, I looked for vim-markdown help and there is none)

Comment: Why don't you try [the issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/issues) [trackers](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues)?

Comment: In this case, I am not sure if it is `neovim` or `vim-markdown` question.

Comment: you can use `verbose set conceallevel` to see which script change this option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those chars are hidden because the `conceal` feature as you can see on the vim-markdown [source](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/blob/63074a52/syntax/markdown.vim#L84-L90).

You can adjust how to this feature is applied to text using the option [`conceallevel`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'conceallevel'). Setting it to `0` will always show the text.

```
:set conceallevel=0
```

Comment: OK, that works...

Comment: I added the following line to my .vimrc file `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.md set conceallevel=0`, but it does not apply, why?  I wonder if some plugin changes it after the autocmd does, unless I am not setting it correctly.

Comment: The same as @user1135541 here: set conceallevel=0 is ignored for json files. Is there a way to get which plugin causes that?